# Formatting preference values onSharedPreferenceChanged

Tags: java, android

I want to remove trailing slashes from a shared preference called `url` after it has been changed.

It seems to be working fine, but in my code, I am updating the summary of all EditTextPreferences after they are changed to contain their values.

My problem is that even though the trailing slash has been removed from the `url`, I don't actually see the changes in the EditTextPreference summary until I close and re-open the preference activity.

I've tried using `commit()` instead of `apply()` and it didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SettingsFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(findPreference("service_running"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            Preference preference = getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i);
            updatePreference(preference);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // remove trailing slashes from url
        if (key.equals("url")) {
            String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");

            if (value.endsWith("/")) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(key, value.substring(0, value.length() - 1));
                editor.apply();
            }
        }

        updatePreference(findPreference(key));
    }

    private void updatePreference (Preference preference) {
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference)preference;
            editTextPreference.setSummary(editTextPreference.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setText` instead of the `Editor` resolved the issue.

Code:

```
    if (key.equals("url")) {
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");

        if (value.endsWith("/")) {
            EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference(key);
            editTextPreference.setText(value.substring(0, value.length() - 1));
        }
    }
```